# 'Continue' Function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, continue

I have a question about the 'continue' function in Python. I wolud like to skip 'Antarctic' in the following list:

```
continents = = ["Afrika", "Antarktic", "Asien", "Australia", "Europe", "North America", "South America"]
```

I thought about using the for loop in combination with the 'continue' function but it doesn't work. Maybe I have to transform the list in another format or so.

This was my first guess.

```
for i in continents:
    if i == 1:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI: `continue` is not a function. Also why you expect `i` to ever contain `1` if you iterate over `continents`? `i` is a value, not index. want index? try `enumerate()`

Comment: You need to decide whether you want to iterate over indices or elements of the array.

Comment: You are iterating the list items directly. So you have to pass the item name instead of index. Just replace i==1 with i=='Antarktic'

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample list:

```py
continents = [
  "Afrika",
  "Antarktic",
  "Asien",
  "Australia",
  "Europe",
  "North America",
  "South America",
]
```

You are iterating through this list, so `i` is the value of each string as you're going along:

```py
for i in continents:  # i: str
```

So at this point, you just need to compare each string to your value to skip it:

```py
  if i == "Antarktic":
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Having the list as:

```py
continents = [
    "Afrika",
    "Antarktic",
    "Asien",
    "Australia",
    "Europe",
    "North America",
    "South America",
]
```

These are two of the many approaches that work:

```py
for el in continents:
    if el == "Antarktic":
        continue
    print(el)
```

```py
for i, el in enumerate(continents):
    if i == 1:
        continue
    print(i, el)
```

Also, `continue` is a **statement** and not a function. You can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-continue-statement/).

Answer (score 0):

1.First of all the assignment of values in list will give error. `==` is used for checking equal condition. use = for assignment.

```
continents = ["Afrika", "Antarktic", "Asien", "Australia", "Europe", "North America", "South America"]
```

2. `for i in continents:`

It symbolize that you are iterating over values not indices so according to above for loop the if condn will never met.
Two solution for this.

a.

```
     `
       for i in continents:
           if i == "Antarktic:
              continue 
           print(i)
     `
```

b.

```
     `
      for i in range(len(continents)):
          if i ==1:
             continue
          print(i)
     `
```

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong, you want to skip the print function, if the value is equals to "Antarctica".

```
continents = [
    "Afrika",
    "Antarctica",
    "Asien",
    "Australia",
    "Europe",
    "North America",
    "South America",
]

# If want to skip based on the value, use below code
for i in continents:
    if i == "Antarctica":
        continue
    else:
        print(i)

# If want to skip based on the index, use below code
for i in continents:
    if continents.index(i) == 1 :
        continue
    else:
        print(i)
```

but this is not the perfect scenario for using **"continue"**, anyway it will work.